# Three.js with Angular version 16+ dont work

Tags: angular, three.js

i want to integrate three.js into my angular 16 project, i get the following error message:

```
npm i @angular-three/core
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: xxx@0.0.1
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@16.1.7
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"^16.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^14.0.0" from @angular-three/core@6.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular-three/core
npm ERR!   @angular-three/core@"^6.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

is it possible to use threejs only with angular14 or is there a workaround? or am i doing something wrong i have also used the "--force" command, this does not work

Answer (score 1):

Angular Three author here.

`@angular-three/core` has been archived for a while. Please check out `angular-three` and the documentation at https://angular-threejs.netlify.app